# jQuery: Adding rows to a table

Tags: jquery, html, append, html-table

I'm completely new to JavaScript and jQuery and now I am trying to modify a html table.

Every time a button is clicked, the some stuff (input, text, button) should be added as the last row. I managed that for the first row, but when I click the button again, the next input will be added next to the last row and not under it. I don't understand why. Hope you can help.

This is my html file:

```html
...
<main>
  <article id="main">
    ...
    <section id="neue vorschlaege">
      ...
      <table id="vorschlaege"> 
        <tr> 
          <td>Deine Idee</td>
          <td>Vorschläge</td>
          <td>Kategorie</td>
          <td>Löschen</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- I want to insert new rows here -->
      </table>
    </section>
  </article>
  ...
</main>
```

And this is my jQuery.js:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#abschicken').on('click', function(add){
    add.preventDefault();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var fvv = $('input[name=FVV]:radio:checked').next('label:first').html();
    var zutaten = $("#zutaten").val();
    var passwort = $("#pw").val();

    $('#vorschlaege > tbody:last-child').append(
      '</tr>'
      +'<td><input type="checkbox" checked="true"></td>'
      +'<td>'+name+'</td>'
      +'<td>'+fvv+'</td>'
      +'<td><button id="loeschen">löschen</button></td>'
      +'</tr>');
  });
});
```

Comment: You are closing a tr in the first line of the append

Comment: The simplest solution..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You started with a `</tr>`closing tag.

```
$('#vorschlaege > tbody:last-child').append(
            '<tr>'// need to change closing tag to an opening `<tr>` tag.
            +'<td><input type="checkbox" checked="true"></td>'
            +'<td>'+name+'</td>'
            +'<td>'+fvv+'</td>'
            +'<td><button id="loeschen">löschen</button></td>'
            +'</tr>');
```

Comment: someone already commented on that... thank you. i can't believe i didn't see that. ;D